# No PreValidation stage when converting email to case

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm

I have a plugin triggering *pre-validation* of *create incident* to assign ticketnumber before the built-in numbering does that. It works like a charm.

But when I have an email and use the **Convert to Case** button, *pre-validation* never triggers. I can only get plugins to fire on *pre-operation*, where the ticketnumber is already assigned.

Anyone know how to get around that? Is there another message to look for? Or is the only way to change my plugin to "detect" if the oob numbering has kicked in and let it fire on pre-operation?

And is there no pre-validation stage available for cases created from email?

(of course I could have my plugin always assign my own numbers, but it is a generic plugin that can be used for any entity and is designed to be unobtrusive, and I would like to keep it that way. I would also prefer it to run pre-operation, but oob numbering strikes at the *internal pre-operation* stage)

Comment: On a side note, can you still generate you own ticket number & update the case if the existing ticket number is not in your own format, did you try?

Comment: Yes that works just fine, no problem there. The thing is I would have wanted to use the generic forgiving approach (for any entity/attribute) that if a number is already assigned it should keep that. But I can overwrite, absolutely.

Answer (score 3):

In the *Convert to Case* scenario you can only register steps in the *pre-operation* and *post-operation* stages of the *Create* message for the *incident* entity.

In general the *pre-validation* stage is only available for the message associated with the original `OrganizationRequest`, but for *Convert to Case* there is no such API request and the conversion is handled by the application layer of the system.

The application breaks the conversion process up into create and update messages and for these atomic operations only the plugin pre and post stages can be used.

The pre operation stage of the Create message is the step best suited to add a unique ticket number, because at that point the plugin executes in a database transaction.

Comment: Thanks for verifying my observations :) Have you found any documentation supporting this internal behavior? This seems to be one of those things you just "discover" during development...

Comment: In many cases the best option is to go through trial and error, e.g. register a test plugin on many steps and attach a debugger. For Dynamics CRM 4.0 Microsoft distinguished parent and child plugin pipelines. Prevalidation stages were only available in the parent pipeline and the remaining steps for the child pipeline could only be registered for the Create, Update and Delete messages. In CRM 2011 MS simplified this model, so developers do not need to register steps for a specific pipeline any more, but internally this distinction still exists. Unforunately this is no longer documented.

Comment: And luckily we are going towards even more simple architecture, with strict CRUD messages. I was just hoping you had found The Hidden Document telling us about this sort of things ;)

Comment: I googled a few blog articles on the pipeline topic: http://crmscape.blogspot.nl/2009/02/ms-crm-40-plug-in-stages-pipelines-and.html, http://msdynamicscrm4all.blogspot.nl/2011/09/difference-between-parent-and-child.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31134751/do-you-still-need-to-check-the-parent-child-pipelines-to-determine-whether-to